# captcha box not rendering properly IE10 compat IE 7 standard

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, captcha

My default work browser is IE10 which is admin set to compatibility mode using IE7 standards.  I have no way of influencing this decision, but do have access to F12 to change it on a page by page basis.

When I asked a question to increase my work productivity, the captcha box for "I am not a robot" failed to render prior to my use of F12 to change to IE10 (without compatibility mode).

Just wanted to make you all aware of this issue.

Comment: Since IE7 [is not supported by Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need), I'd say the bug is most likely [tag:status-bydesign], or [tag:status-declined].